# Allowing users to input a safe subset of HTML

Tags: php, html, security, validation

I am currently working on a project that requires users to input text that may or may not be formatted (if it helps, just think of it as a Stack Exchange clone, even though that's not quite accurate). Instead of opting for some sort of BB Code or other markup language to allow users to format their text, I figure it'd probably less stressful for the user to just use a subset of HTML. My users are all generally pretty experienced computer users, so I don't expect that to be much of an issue.

My plan is to have a whitelist of tags and attributes. Anything that doesn't match the whitelist will be removed. I figure that as long as I don't accidentally allow a dangerous attribute or element and I implement the code well, there won't be any problems.

I think I generally implemented the code well, but my knowledge of security issues is shaky at best, hence why I'm posting the code here.

```
public function set($value){
    /*
        First, I want to make sure that we're dealing with a string, so I cast it to a string. Should I throw an error if it's not a string instead?

        Next, I transform \n to <br>, so that whitespace appears correctly. I think it might be better to skip this step and use a CSS rule to allow whitespace.
    */
    $value    =    (string) $value;
    $value    =    nl2br(trim($value));

    /*
        Here is my whitelist. Notice the multiple br elements.
    */
    $value    =    strip_tags($value, "<a><img><table><tr><td><th><h2><h3><h4><blockquote><ul><ol><li><br><br/><br />");

    /*
        This caused some issues in my tests, where it'd unnecessarily escape certain things, so I commented it out. Are shell command injections something I need to worry about?
    */
    //$value    =    escapeshellcmd($value);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    if($value === ""){
        return false;
    }
    $dom->loadHTML($value);

    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach($nodes as $node){
        if($node->hasAttributes()){
            foreach($node->attributes as $attr){
                $name    =    $attr->name;
                $value    =    $attr->value;
                switch($name){
                    /*
                        These elements are generally safe. Worst case scenario, someone just creates some weird looking HTML, which I'm not too worried about.
                    */
                    case "id":        break;
                    case "style":    break;
                    case "src":        break;
                    case "alt":        break;
                    case "class":    break;
                    /*
                        This is my biggest concern. You can embed inline javascript with <a href="javascript:foo();"></a>, so I want to prevent this. However, links are important so I don't want to completely strip this attribute.
                    */
                    case "href": 
                        if(strpos($value, "javascript") !== false){
                            $node->removeAttribute($name);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        $node->removeAttribute($name);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $value    =    $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement->firstChild);

    /*
        PHP is weird and adds a bunch of extra elements around the HTML, and it's easiest to just strip the tags again. It's a little hacky, but it works every time (I think).
    */
    $value    =    strip_tags($value, "<a><img><table><tr><td><th><h2><h3><h4><blockquote><ul><ol><li><br><br/><br />");

    /*
        I don't exactly remember why this is here. I think it ensures that all br elements are in the same format, but it probably doesn't do a very good job at it.
    */
    $value    =    str_replace("br/", "br", $value);

    /*
        This ensures that our input is the right length. I chose to do this after we removed all the junk just as a little present for the user.
    */
    if(strlen($value) > $this->length){
        $this->text    =    substr($value, 0, $this->length);
    }else{
        $this->text    =    $value;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I'm not too worried about SQL injection so my biggest concern is XSS and I guess any forms of injection that I'm not familiar with.

[Here's a link to a more testable version of the code](http://codepad.org/ADHTAlav).

Changes that I'll be making:

- Use a case insensitive search when checking URLs for "javascript:"
- Remove the style attribute from the whitelist (now I need a way for users to bold/italicize their text, I'll probably allow `<b>` and `<i>`, I guess)
- Check image src's against a whitelist
- Remove the `nl2br` stuff and use `white-space: pre-wrap` in my CSS instead

[Here's what I currently have](http://codepad.org/0KYRIimy)

Comment: `strip_tags` may be a little too much. You get questions on Stack Overflow like "I tried (newline) it didn't work", where it makes no sense because the HTML example is hidden.

Comment: I think `strip_tags` is appropriate. My users won't be posting code snippets, so I don't need to worry about that.

Comment: You can introduce yourself by saying "Hi, my name is **<name>**"

Comment: Hmm...good point. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to parse it. There are libraries for that. I made an Stack Overflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22184073/2888561) too.

Comment: That code's pretty messy so I can't completely tell what's going on, but it looks a little brittle (Regex is pretty easy to break). I'd rather just have `<name>` be removed than be afraid someone will break my sanitizer.

Comment: I guess being afraid is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah I figure having `<name>` disappear is a pretty minor issue. I could remove `strip_tags` and just validate the tag name against a whitelist and then convert any issues to entities.

Comment: That would work. Just make sure you aren't displaying all the warnings DOMDocument spits out when the HTML is malformed.

Comment: [I should use a case-insensitive search when seeing if JavaScript is embedded in a href attribute.](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dm38/)

Comment: Maybe HTML is less stressful for your users but markdown is less stressful for you.

Comment: Allowing custom `style` attributes may not be safe.  See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.234_-_CSS_Escape_And_Strictly_Validate_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Style_Property_Values

Comment: @FoolishSeth Thank you very much for pointing that out. I would've never found it on my own.

Comment: I'll also run image src's through a whitelist, to prevent IP harvesting.

Comment: The only safe way of doing this that I know of: Parse input in to your own tree structure. Using javascript, create a specific node for each allowed command and insert remaining parts in to text nodes. More specifically do not insert ANY user provided text/html in to the html document it self. The browsers are just too nice in fixing bad syntax, don't try to be smart.

Comment: I decided that the only attributes I need to whitelist are `href` and `src`. I should pass their values through a URL validator.

Comment: @Meredith, you may want to try posting a question on http://security.stackexchange.com/ I think that you may receive a better answer there than you would here, even though this question is on-topic here on CodeReview.  if you do decide to post on Security please be aware that they are a different kind of site than CodeReview and please read their [Help page links](http://security.stackexchange.com/help) on [What topics can I ask about here?](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I read up on getElementsByTagName() and it is unclear to me if you can rely on returned tags or attribute names being converted to lowercase only. If not, you may need to fold the input tags and attributes to the preferred case for comparisons (e.g. case "href").

Answer (score 8):

The way I see it, you must protect yourself from the following types of attacks:

1. XSS (Javascript injection to run on the browser)
2. PHP Injection
3. Information Disclosure

Allowing `<img src="whatever"/>` violates #3, so malicious users can embed a transparent pixel and see everyone who looks at a given page. I believe the `style` attribute could accomplish the same attack.

You may be vulnerable to PHP injection if you're ever careless about how you embed this user-generated content into your web pages. This can be very serious, because PHP runs on the server. It would expose any SQL databases and perhaps the whole system and network.

It appears that your code is vulnerable to XSS because Javascript can be embedded in the `style` attribute. You'll have to check what can be embedded in every attribute for [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) and HTML5. XSS attacks are serious because the script has access to your website with the current users session. In general XSS attacks can steal cookies, make new posts to propagate the XSS attack to other users, and attempt to change user account settings.

In my opinion, allowing users to embed HTML is dangerous, and you'd better do your homework. You'd be better off using some alternate markup like StackExchange uses.

Comment: I fixed the `style` attribute issue (the most recent version is at the bottom of my question). I think I'll run image src's against a whitelist (imgur, puush, etc) so tracking images can't be used. Could you expand on PHP injection?

Comment: I don't think PHP injection is very common, but if you ever pass user input into eval(), system(), passthru(), deserialize(), or similar functions then you're at risk.

Comment: Alright, I don't do any of those so I should be safe

Answer (score 4):

[PHP strip_tags Documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

you should check out the documentation and what people are saying about the function as well so that you know exactly what is happening with the code you are using.

---

I would also heavily test this against HTML5 elements,  or add those elements if you wish to whitelist them as well,  from the documentation it seems you are protected from the PHP tags already.  you should find the newest list of HTML/XHTML tags and test the usage with all of them.

---

Something that is already mentioned in the Comments is the `href`'s and the `src`'s you said that you would whitelist these, but the problem isn't always whether the information they inject is dangerous to you.

Case in point, someone posts a normal link like `<a href="http://www.not-a-real-site-but-a-virus-injection-point.com>Click here</a>` and it passes your whitelist so it is visible on your message board or chat room,  but when someone clicks the link it runs a script on that webpage in the client browser.

This attack could leave their account (on your site) vulnerable and you would never know it, and neither would they.

There is an insane amount of XSS vulnerabilities out there, and the list grows every day, which means that the only thing you can do is to keep reading about security issues on the internet and Testing your Application accordingly.

---

Links

[XSS Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

[OWASP Cross-site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)

OWASP is a good source for security information from what I have read

Here is a Cheat Sheet from OWASP for XSS vulnerability protection

[XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer and seems to miss the entire point of the question.

Comment: @Meredith, how so?  I meant to say HTML5 elements, as it has new HTML elements,  you should also check to make sure that the XHTML elements are stripped as well, that may be more difficult though as you can pretty much create what you want.

Comment: The question asks how to enforce that a user's input is a safe subset of HTML. Saying little more than "HTML5 introduced new elements" isn't an on topic answer.

Comment: you are already whitelisting a safe subset, using an old PHP funciton,  I am saying that I would test it to make sure that it works first, then you can go from there.

Comment: `strip_tags` removes all elements that aren't in the whitelist. It removes `<name>` (an element that doesn't exist) just as well as it removes `<canvas>` (an HTML5 element) and `<div>`.

Comment: Also regarding `<a href="http://www.not-a-real-site-but-a-virus-injection-point.com>Click here</a>`, I don't think that's a huge problem. It'd still be an issue unless I outright disallowed links and really the only way to solve it is to have moderators remove fishy links.

Comment: you are welcome, and I agree @Meredith.  but I think those links will help when looking for XSS vulnerabilities, I have only touched on learning about them myself.